# Simulate Single/Double Tap Swift

Tags: swift, charts

Is it possible to simulate a single/double tap through Swift? I am using the Charts library from GitHub, and it has the ability to highlight an area when selected (finger pressed), but when you remove your finger, the area stays selected. I'd like to add the ability that when the finger selection is done, to simulate a single tap on the same place, or a double tap elsewhere on the graph, as that de-selects the area. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to add an `UITapGestureRecognizer`, for example:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.handleTap(sender:)))
chartView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Then you have to implement the handler:

```
@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    // call the touch chart event here 
}
```

After that, to simulate the tap, you just call the `handleTap()` function